# ENIGMA CATALYST - WARNING: Loader: Refusing to download new treasury data because a download succeeded

Tags: python, zipline, enigma2, enigma-catalyst

I'm playing around with [Enigma Catalyst](https://enigmampc.github.io/catalyst/example-algos.html#). Unfortunately, the documentation is rather limited.

So I'm trying to run their example "hello world" type algo which looks as follows:

```
from catalyst import run_algorithm
from catalyst.api import order, record, symbol
import pandas as pd

def initialize(context):
    context.asset = symbol('btc_usd')


def handle_data(context, data):
    order(context.asset, 1)
    record(btc=data.current(context.asset, 'price'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_algorithm(
        capital_base=10000,
        data_frequency='daily',
        initialize=initialize,
        handle_data=handle_data,
        exchange_name='Bitfinex',
        algo_namespace='buy_and_hodl',
        base_currency='usd',
        start=pd.to_datetime('2018-01-02', utc=True),
        end=pd.to_datetime('2018-01-03', utc=True),
    )
```

I realize according to the documentation [it says you first need to "ingest" download the historical data](https://enigmampc.github.io/catalyst/beginner-tutorial.html) which I believe I did. However this leads to the following error:

> ```
> [2018-02-25 02:54:10.696049] WARNING: Loader: Refusing to download new
> treasury data because a download succeeded at 2018-02-25
> 02:08:26.001177+00:00.
> ```

Which results in no data

> ```
> [2018-02-25 02:54:10.830665] INFO: Performance: first open: 2018-01-02
> 00:00:00+00:00 [2018-02-25 02:54:10.830665] INFO: Performance: last
> close: 2018-01-03 23:59:00+00:00
> ```

Question:

How do I access the downloaded data? Or, how do I delete and re-download the historical data, which is not covered in the docs?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out with help from core Catalyst developer on Discord. Pricing data gets downloaded from the Catalyst server as data bundles on your local machine. You have to start the catalyst environment every time you plan to use it. When in the Enigma Catalyst environment you can clear data bundles (previously downloaded pricing data) using the `catalyst clean` command.